# Where do I ask a question about line endings in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about Visual Studio 2017 for Mac. Possible target communities are:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (tools for programming)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (program use)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (Apple questions)

> How do I change the line endings of all source files in an existing project in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac?

Which is the best community to ask my question?

Comment: Also, under the "File" menu is there an "Advanced Save Options..." on the Mac?

Comment: @ColleenV I've asked my question on [so] [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52109695/1166898)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend one of the first two choices, Stack Overflow or Super User.

While questions about third-party software that runs on Apple hardware are technically on-topic for that site, from what I can tell, most of the questions are about hardware and software made by Apple, and the questions have to indicate how they're specific to Apple products. Your question technically fits that, but it might seem off-topic at first glance.

Stack Overflow accepts questions about software development tools, and as that has a bigger community, you'll probably get your answer quicker there.

Answer (score 3):

Go with what you're touching the most in the context of the problem. In your case, it's Visual Studio (which is a tool commonly used by programmers and is firmly on-topic on SO). The fact that you are running on a Mac is *relevant*, but broadly incidental, it's a VS question.

If it was about trying to figure out why the fan spins up so high and the CPU seems to throttle while you drag a VS window from monitor to monitor, then maybe Ask Different would be the better choice.

But again, in the second example, you're concern is the hardware, VS just becomes an example of something CPU or I/O bound that reproduces a *hardware* problem.

Or, (my favorite) pick based on which inanimate thing you're barking at the most. Is it the laptop itself, or the program running on it? :)